# I'm trying to create simple bungee cord command plugin

Tags: java, plugins, server, command, bungeecord

The problem is when I put my jar file into the plugins folder and ran the server I always got this message from console:

`Enabled plugin FirstCommand version 1.0-SNAPSHOT by null`

My code consists of 2 classes:

```java
public final class FirstCommand extends Plugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
        getLogger().info("has loaded");
        getProxy().getPluginManager().registerCommand(this, new PingCommand());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }
}
```

and

```java
public class PingCommand extends Command {

    public PingCommand() {
        super("ping");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(CommandSender sender, String[] args) {
        if (sender instanceof ProxiedPlayer) {
            ProxiedPlayer player = (ProxiedPlayer) sender;
            int ping = player.getPing();
            player.sendMessage(new TextComponent(ChatColor.GRAY + "Your ping is: " + ChatColor.GREEN + ping));
        }
    }
}
```

```yaml
bungee.yml : 
name: FirstCommand
version: ${project.version}
main: org.example.firstcommand.FirstCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what is the issue with that message.

Is the `null` at the end of the message bothering you? Specify author in your plugin.yml

```yaml
name: FirstCommand
version: ${project.version}
author: ShashaS
main: org.example.firstcommand.FirstCommand
```

Or the command isn't working properly?